# I need to remove duplicates from an Array of items

Tags: arrays, jsp, jstl, set

I'm not really a coder so please have an open mind when it comes to what I call different aspects of the code. I might be dead wrong about what things are actually called...

Anyhow I (believe) I have an array of item containing lots of different data attached to each item. I then iterate over this Array putting the content into my jsp. The problem is that the array contains duplicates and I don't want duplicates in the presentation on the homepage.

I have googled like a freak and I have found out that the way to remove duplicates is to convert the array to a set, since a set can't contain duplicates. Fair enough. I have checked different pages describing how to go about it but I don't understand :(

It's probably very simple but from what I can make of it the sets contain strings and that won't do it for me as my items have a lot of data attached to them item.name, item.type etc.

The code I use is

```
<c:forEach items="${results.searchResults}" var="foundItem" varStatus="status">
    <c:set var="curItem" value="${foundItem.item}" />
    <%-- get item details --%>
    <xmlfeed:getItemXML item="${curItem}" />
</c:forEach>
```

And what I want to do is make sure that all curItem's are unique. I bet the best way to do this is to make sure that the "results.searchResults" array is made into a set and then turned back but I just don't understand how to do it.

Perhaps worth mentioning, the above code is actually already inside a tag with the following taglibs availible:

taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"

along with the custom xmlfeed tablib of course

Comment: So, you want how to return unique set from results.searchResults()

Answer (score 1):

In your `result` Object there is a `List<Item> searchResults` variable? You can change it to `Set<String> searchResults;` and in the setter or any other method which is setting data for `searchResults` variable do `this.searchResults = new HashSet<String>(resultlist);`

following code may not be the exact way for you but it will help to find your own way.....

```
public class Result {

    private List<String> result;
    private Set<String> searchResults;

    public Set<String> getSearchResults() {
        return searchResults;
    }

    public void setResult(List<String> result) {
        this.result = result;
        this.searchResults = new HashSet<String>(result);
    }
}
```

Servlet code,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("A");
Result result = new Result();
result.setResult(list);
request.setAttribute("result", result);

request.getRequestDispatcher("testPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In JSP,

```
<c:forEach items="${result.searchResults}" var="foundItem" varStatus="status">
    <c:set var="curItem" value="${foundItem}" />
    ${curItem}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I'd prefer `LinkedHashSet` over `HashSet` as it maintains the list order.

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually shares some light on the situation for me. Problem however is that my classes are already compiled and I don't have the option of redoing them. Does this mean I'm screwed with what I'm trying to do? Or is there a way to handle the conversion directly in the Tag albeit an ugly solution? 

What I was thinking of is that within the Tag intercept the ${results} so that no two curItems can be the same or Perhaps a test within the forEach loop to make sure that all the output is unique. Ignoring duplicates in some way.

Again thank you very very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Set<String> searchResults()
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");list.add("B"); list.add("A");list.add("B");list.add("A");
    return new HashSet<String>(list);
}
```

The above code returns the unique list.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm sorry, I don't understand how to implement this :( The thing is that I need the original code in place because all the variables in it are used. So, what I need to do is make sure that the output in the forEach are all unique. I guess by making sure that the data passed to "foundItem" is free from duplicates. I'm sorry if I'm being fuzzy. I will gladly elaborate, I just need to know what to elaborate.